# how do I return values from a specific year for years in the future

Tags: powerbi, dax

I have two tables: a fact-table with hours spent, and a date dimensions table.

factTableHours:
| employeeName | hours | datekey |

dimDate: (from year 2000-2030)
| datekey | year | month | day |

I'm trying to create a simple estimate of how many hours an employee is going to spend in the future by looking at the hours he spent the last whole year. 
It's similar to the SAMEPERIODLASTYEAR function, but i want a specific year based on today's date.
So, if I did it today, I would like it to return the time registered in 2015, 
in order to get an estimate of how many hours he will spend in the coming years, 2016, 2017, 2018...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution with the help of this page: https://www.sqlbi.com/articles/week-based-time-intelligence-in-dax/
I only needed another column in my time dimension, the day number of the year

```
hoursIn2015 :=
    IF (
    HASONEVALUE ( dimDate[year] ),
    CALCULATE (
        SUM ( factTableHours[hours] ),
        FILTER (
            ALL ( dimDate),
            dimDate[year] = 2015
                && CONTAINS(
                    VALUES ( dimDate[Day number in year] ),
                    dimDate[Day number in year],
                    dimDate[Day number in year] )
        )
    ),
    BLANK ()
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this - With this Statement you get the figures from last year:

```
[PY Sales] = CALCULATE([Sales Amount]),DATEADD('Date'[Date],-1,YEAR)
```

BTW - here is a good reference for DAX Time Patterns:

http://www.daxpatterns.com/time-patterns/

Comment: thanks, but this will return the previous year: 2017 values for 2018, 2018 values for 2019 etc. I want it to do almost the same thing, but for a fixed year. so that no matter if i look at 2019,2020 or 2021 it will return the values for 2015.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a measure that calculates the last year hours.

Using the `TODAY()` function you will get the today's date, so we need to substract one year.

```
HoursLastYear =
CALCULATE (
    SUM ( factTableHours[hours] ),
    FILTER (
        dimDate,
        dimDate[datekey]
            = DATE ( YEAR ( TODAY () ) - 1, MONTH ( TODAY () ), DAY ( TODAY () ) )
    )
)
```

Let me know if this helps.

Comment: well that's about half the way. Now i need it to return the value from that formula, on the dates in the future. like the SAMEPERIODLASTYEAR does. so that when i look on the year 2019 it will give me the values from 2015

Comment: @Nikolaj, how will you relate employeename with 2017+ dates, what is your expected result? Note there is no relationship between your fact table and dimdate using future dates.

Comment: yes that is exactly the problem. the values for an employee on future dates doesn't exists, obviously. that is why i would like to show hours spent in 2015 for future dates. In order to get a crude estimate of how many hours he will spend.

Comment: @Nikolaj, I think there is no way to artificially relate the fact table with future dates in the dimDate table. I think a workaround could be create a calculated column in the dimDate table containing the last year date for every future date, i.e 2017-01-01 in datekey should hold the 2015-01-01 value in the calculated column, then you can use the calculated column to get the values from the fact table. Another alternative is to create a fact estimate table with datekeys from 2016+, then create a calculated column to retrieve the corresponding value for the last year date.

Comment: i was afraid of that :-) thanks for your suggestions, i will try an see if I can come up with something